# How to Invert nested array/objects structure and rekeying by lowest object?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have lodash 4.17 available

I have the following API response structure:

```
{
    "things": [
        {
            "id": 14500,
            "name": "Q1 Out Ind",
            "thing_type_id": 6,
            "owner_id": 1680,
            "owner": {
                "id": 1680,
                "model_id": 602
            },
            "thing_type": {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "The Type of Thing"
            },
            "related_things": [
                {
                    "id": 9749,
                    "name": "unnamed thing",
                    "thing_id": 14500,
                    "more_things": [
                        {
                            "id": 16166,
                            "name": "Num Thing Sum",
                            "datasource_object_id": 9408,
                            "thing_id": 9749,
                            "external_datasource": {
                                "id": 9408,
                                "parent_id": 2810,
                                "target_id": 15028
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 14503,
            "name": "Q2 Out Ind",
            "thing_type_id": 6,
            "owner_id": 1681,
            "owner": {
                "id": 1681,
                "model_id": 602
            },
            "thing_type": {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "The Type of Thing"
            },
            "related_things": [
                {
                    "id": 9750,
                    "name": "unnamed thing2",
                    "thing_id": 14503,
                    "more_things": [
                        {
                            "id": 16167,
                            "name": "Num Thing Avg",
                            "datasource_object_id": 9409,
                            "thing_id": 9750,
                            "external_datasource": {
                                "id": 9409,
                                "parent_id": 2810,
                                "target_id": 15029
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 16168,
                            "name": "Num Thing Count",
                            "datasource_object_id": 9408,
                            "thing_id": 9750,
                            "external_datasource": {
                                "id": 9408,
                                "parent_id": 2810,
                                "target_id": 15028
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And I am trying to get a list of objects matching specific `target_id` at the very end of the nesting.

So far, the following works only if there is one result in the array:

```
_.filter(things.things, 
      function (obj) {
        return obj.related_things[0].more_things[0].external_datasource.target_id == 15028;
      }
  )
```

However, as you see in this example, in this case it has two "things" at the end of which, there is a match as there is array for `more_things` and `related_things` - how do I adjust my lodash filter to search across any depth? I need a list of matching objects, to display various attributes in the UI related to the matched targets.

Comment: you need `some`. btw do you need the whole big thing back or just the small object with the `external_datasource` field

Comment: I need the whole thing back as the parents contain attributes I need to display. Looking at `some` now

Comment: @cmgchess I've read the `some` documentation, still unclear how do I apply it instead of hardcoded `[0]` in my initial solution?

Comment: There is only one item with target_id matching.  There is another item with question_id matching.

Comment: @James my apologies! edited, it is supposed to be `target_id` :)

Comment: Updated again, it should be good now. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have nested `_some` functions inside the `filter`. By the way this is also possible with native array `filter` and `some`

```js
const things = {    "things": [        {            "id": 14500,            "name": "Q1 Out Ind",            "thing_type_id": 6,            "owner_id": 1680,            "owner": {                "id": 1680,                "model_id": 602            },            "thing_type": {                "id": 6,                "name": "The Type of Thing"            },            "related_things": [                {                    "id": 9749,                    "name": "unnamed thing",                    "thing_id": 14500,                    "more_things": [                        {                            "id": 16166,                            "name": "Num Thing Sum",                            "datasource_object_id": 9408,                            "thing_id": 9749,                            "external_datasource": {                                "id": 9408,                                "parent_id": 2810,                                "target_id": 15028                            }                        }                    ]                }            ]        },        {            "id": 14503,            "name": "Q2 Out Ind",            "thing_type_id": 6,            "owner_id": 1681,            "owner": {                "id": 1681,                "model_id": 602            },            "thing_type": {                "id": 6,                "name": "The Type of Thing"            },            "related_things": [                {                    "id": 9750,                    "name": "unnamed thing2",                    "thing_id": 14503,                    "more_things": [                        {                            "id": 16167,                            "name": "Num Thing Avg",                            "datasource_object_id": 9409,                            "thing_id": 9750,                            "external_datasource": {                                "id": 9409,                                "parent_id": 2810,                                "target_id": 15029                            }                        },                        {                            "id": 16168,                            "name": "Num Thing Count",                            "datasource_object_id": 9408,                            "thing_id": 9750,                            "external_datasource": {                                "id": 9408,                                "form_id": 2810,                                "target_id": 15028                            }                        }                    ]                }            ]        }    ]}

const id = 15028

const res = _.filter(things.things, a => {
  return _.some(a.related_things, b => {
    return _.some(b.more_things, c => c.external_datasource.target_id === id)
  })
})

console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

without lodash

```js
const things = {    "things": [        {            "id": 14500,            "name": "Q1 Out Ind",            "thing_type_id": 6,            "owner_id": 1680,            "owner": {                "id": 1680,                "model_id": 602            },            "thing_type": {                "id": 6,                "name": "The Type of Thing"            },            "related_things": [                {                    "id": 9749,                    "name": "unnamed thing",                    "thing_id": 14500,                    "more_things": [                        {                            "id": 16166,                            "name": "Num Thing Sum",                            "datasource_object_id": 9408,                            "thing_id": 9749,                            "external_datasource": {                                "id": 9408,                                "parent_id": 2810,                                "target_id": 15028                            }                        }                    ]                }            ]        },        {            "id": 14503,            "name": "Q2 Out Ind",            "thing_type_id": 6,            "owner_id": 1681,            "owner": {                "id": 1681,                "model_id": 602            },            "thing_type": {                "id": 6,                "name": "The Type of Thing"            },            "related_things": [                {                    "id": 9750,                    "name": "unnamed thing2",                    "thing_id": 14503,                    "more_things": [                        {                            "id": 16167,                            "name": "Num Thing Avg",                            "datasource_object_id": 9409,                            "thing_id": 9750,                            "external_datasource": {                                "id": 9409,                                "parent_id": 2810,                                "target_id": 15029                            }                        },                        {                            "id": 16168,                            "name": "Num Thing Count",                            "datasource_object_id": 9408,                            "thing_id": 9750,                            "external_datasource": {                                "id": 9408,                                "form_id": 2810,                                "target_id": 15028                            }                        }                    ]                }            ]        }    ]}

const id = 15028

const res = things.things.filter(a => {
  return a.related_things.some(b => {
    return b.more_things.some(c => c.external_datasource.target_id === id)
  })
})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Works, I understand now how to do this, thanks!

Comment: @Carmageddon it is O(n^3) however cant help that

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly why I opted to do this on the client side rather than server side :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flatMap` and `some` with `filter`

```js
const things= {
    "things": [

   {
        "id": 1450033333,
        "name": "SHOULD NOT BE IN THE RESULTS",
        "thing_type_id": 6,
        "owner_id": 1680,
        "owner": {
            "id": 1680,
            "model_id": 602
        },
        "thing_type": {
            "id": 6,
            "name": "The Type of Thing"
        },
        "related_things": [
            {
                "id": 9749,
                "name": "unnamed thing",
                "thing_id": 14500,
                "more_things": [
                    {
                        "id": 16166,
                        "name": "Num Thing Sum",
                        "datasource_object_id": 9408,
                        "thing_id": 9749,
                        "external_datasource": {
                            "id": 9408,
                            "parent_id": 2810,
                            "target_id": 15024
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
   
        {
            "id": 14500,
            "name": "Q1 Out Ind",
            "thing_type_id": 6,
            "owner_id": 1680,
            "owner": {
                "id": 1680,
                "model_id": 602
            },
            "thing_type": {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "The Type of Thing"
            },
            "related_things": [
                {
                    "id": 9749,
                    "name": "unnamed thing",
                    "thing_id": 14500,
                    "more_things": [
                        {
                            "id": 16166,
                            "name": "Num Thing Sum",
                            "datasource_object_id": 9408,
                            "thing_id": 9749,
                            "external_datasource": {
                                "id": 9408,
                                "parent_id": 2810,
                                "target_id": 15028
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 14503,
            "name": "Q2 Out Ind",
            "thing_type_id": 6,
            "owner_id": 1681,
            "owner": {
                "id": 1681,
                "model_id": 602
            },
            "thing_type": {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "The Type of Thing"
            },
            "related_things": [
                {
                    "id": 9750,
                    "name": "unnamed thing2",
                    "thing_id": 14503,
                    "more_things": [
                        {
                            "id": 16167,
                            "name": "Num Thing Avg",
                            "datasource_object_id": 9409,
                            "thing_id": 9750,
                            "external_datasource": {
                                "id": 9409,
                                "parent_id": 2810,
                                "target_id": 15029
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 16168,
                            "name": "Num Thing Count",
                            "datasource_object_id": 9408,
                            "thing_id": 9750,
                            "external_datasource": {
                                "id": 9408,
                                "parent_id": 2810,
                                "target_id": 15028
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}


const results = _.filter(things.things, thing => {
  const relatedThings = _.flatMap(thing.related_things, 'more_things');
  return _.some(relatedThings, moreThing => moreThing.external_datasource.target_id == 15028);
});
console.log(results)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to me that @cmgchess's solution is more descriptive and easier to see the purpose of it.